# Implementing a model that can have many other models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to implement a model that behaves as a folder that can contain other models of different type. How can I implement this?

This is the database I have (simplified for exemplification):

```
images
    id - integer
    name - string
    format - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string
    length - integer
    codec - string

folder
    id - integer
    name - string
```

I would expect to be able to do `$folder->elements` and obtain a collection of all `Image`s and `Video`s in the `Folder` element.

To do so I'm thinking of a pivot table like the following:

```
folder_elements
    folder_id - integer
    element_id - integer
    element_type -string
```

And use the morphMany relationship that Laravel provides, but I think (according to the examples on the docs) that it's supposed to be used the other way around (when an element belongs to different other elements, not when an element has different other elements).

Can anybody help me accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's many to one relationship, many elements belong to 1 folder -> each element (image/video) contain a foreign key which reference to the id of the folder it belongs to.

Comment: @catcon But if that's the case you would have to have create a method for each relationship. So in order to have a method that returns a collection with all elements do I have to create another one that merges them? Also, in this case items can belong to different folders at the same time, that's why I was thinking of a many to many relationship.

Comment: @Flerex That's true - you should use `->merge()` if you want to return combined collection

Comment: But wait, how about you return a collection like `['images' => ImagesCollection, 'videos' => videosCollection];` - maybe that's better approach

Comment: @senty That would work too, in fact it's nicer as there're not mixed objects in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the understanding how to set these relationships:

```
class Folder hasMany Images
class Folder hasMany Videos
```

Then,

```
public function folderFiles() {
   return new Collection([
      'images' => $this->images,
      'videos' => $this->videos
   ]);
}
```

I didn't test it but you get the idea.